# "Reload the page to get source for ..." in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, autocomplete

I am using ajax for an auto-complete field, initially it was working but recently it has broken.

I have checked the firebug, initially i used to get the JSON array with data for auto-completion, but now I get following message:

> Reload the page to get source for:
>   http://... [my AJAX script URL here]

I know that support has performed some server security changes. So what should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can reload the page. That only shows up if you open the Net tab after the page has loaded.

Comment: Can you use relative url and test it.

Comment: I think this was unnecessarily closed.

Comment: Can you provide your code, please?

Comment: @PeterBishop Sorry, but this question is not actual and old.

Comment: are you doing a cross domain request ?

Answer (score -1):

Like this? `#result` is the elements ID, alternatively you could use a classname like `.result`.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "test.html" );
```